# Minimum value per group between a date range

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to find the minimum value based on each product ID between the start and end information of a column.

Here's the original table would look like:

```
Supplier_ID          Date            Min Per Day      Flag
------------------------------------------------------------
863703036147077      2019-06-14      0                0
863703036147077      2019-06-15      0                0
863703036147077      2019-06-16      48               1
863703036147077      2019-06-17      47               1
863703036147077      2019-06-18      0                0
863703036147077      2019-06-19      0                0
863703036147077      2019-06-20      0                0
863703036147077      2019-06-21      0                0
863703036197742      2019-06-14      0                0
863703036197742      2019-06-15      4                1
863703036197742      2019-06-16      4                1
863703036197742      2019-06-17      0                0
863703036197742      2019-06-18      0                0
863703036197742      2019-06-19      1                1
863703036197742      2019-06-20      2                1
863703036197742      2019-06-21      0                0
```

This is what I want to achieve...splitting the date into 2 columns with a start and end and a last column that give me the min of the min per day.

```
Supplier_ID        StartDate     EndDate       Min
---------------------------------------------------
863703036147077    2019-06-16    2019-06-17    47
863703036197742    2019-06-15    2019-06-17    4
863703036197742    2019-06-19    2019-06-21    1
```

Below a script that I have written but I am not able to proceed further to get the results that I am aiming for.

```
SELECT
    Supplier_Id
    , Date
    , [Min Per Day]
    , CASE WHEN Flag = 1 AND [Min Per Day] > 0 THEN MIN( [Min Per Day] ) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Supplier_Id] ORDER BY [Supplier_Id], Date ASC RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) ELSE NULL END
FROM [Data]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you

```
Select a.Supplier_ID, a.StartDate, a.EndDate, b.Min_Per_Day 
From (
  Select Supplier_ID, Max(Date) As StartDate, Min(Date) As EndDate
  From MyTable
  Group By Supplier_ID
) a
Left Join (
  Select Supplier_ID, Min(Min_Per_Day) As Min_Per_Day
  From MyTable
  Group By Supplier_ID
) b On a.Supplier_ID = b.Supplier_ID
```